# How to fix System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded caused by workflows with email alert?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm trying to execute batch test method on 100 records and get CPU Runtime Limit error.

I placed the Limits.getCpuTime() method in my code and noticed that my code without the workflow segment takes 3148 ms to complete. However, when I activate two workflows that sends emails to one user each, I get the CPU runtime limit error. In total my process without those two workflows takes around 10 seconds to complete while with them activated it takes around 20 seconds.

```
    @IsTest
static void returnIncClientAddress(){
    //Select Required Records
    User                                incidentClient      =   [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username = 'bbaggins@shire.qa.com' LIMIT 1];
    BMCServiceDesk__Category__c         category            =   [SELECT Id FROM BMCServiceDesk__Category__c WHERE Name = 'TestCategory'];
    BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c  service             =   [SELECT ID FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c WHERE Name = 'TestService'];
    BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c  serviceOffering     =   [SELECT ID FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c WHERE Name = 'TestServiceOffering'];

    //Create Incidents
    List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> incidents = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>();
    for(integer i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c incident = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(
            BMCServiceDesk__FKClient__c             =   incidentClient.ID,
            BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c           =   category.ID,
            BMCServiceDesk__FKServiceOffering__c    =   serviceOffering.ID,
            BMCServiceDesk__FKBusinessService__c    =   service.ID,
            BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c             =   awaiting_for_handling
        );
        incidents.add(incident);
    }
    test.startTest();
    insert incidents;
    test.stopTest();
}
```

I expected the email workflows and alerts to be processed in batch and sent without being so expensive in CPU time, but it seems that Salesforce takes a lot of time both checking the workflows rules and executing on them when needed. The majority of the process' time seems to be spent on sending the workflows' emails (which it doesn't actually do because it's a test method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do to control the execution time of Workflow Rules. You could try converting them into Apex and benchmarking to see whether that results in improvement in time consumed, but I suspect the real solution is that you're going to have to dial down your bulk test.

The CPU limit for a transaction is 10 seconds. If your unit test code is already taking approximately 10 seconds to complete without Workflows (I'm not sure exactly what bounds your 3148 ms and 10 s refer to), you've really got only two choices:

- Make the sum total of automation running on insert of this object faster;
- Reduce the quantity of data you're processing in this unit test.

It's not clear what you're actually testing here, but if it's an Apex trigger, you should make sure that it's properly bulkified and does not consume unnecessary CPU time, including through trigger recursion. Reviewing the call stack in your logs (or simply adding `System.debug()` statements) may help with that.

Lastly - make sure you write assertions in your test method. Test methods without assertions are close to worthless.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your kind response. 
The 3148 ms measurement is the time my code runs in context. The gap between this and 10 seconds is the time other processes such as workflows and process builder takes. As the main hit on CPU time originates in the workflow part I thought this will be the place to start and fix the problem. I agree with you completely about the necessity of assertions, but those records merely created to test bulk method so I didn't even had the chance to write the assertion as this step failed before they became relevant.

Comment: Got it, @LiorLavi; sounds like you've done all the profiling you need. I'd suggest reimplementing the workflows in Apex and profiling again if that solution would meet your needs, but the quickest solution is to jettison the bulk unit test. In my experience it's not that common to be able to use substantial data volume in a unit test for exactly this reason.

Comment: Thank you very much David for your help. I decided to reduce the quantity of the data tested as you suggested. It's not a perfect solution as it doesn't really covers my testing scenario to the extent I wanted, but I don't see any other options at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Are there triggers on the BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c or on objects modified by the Workflow?  Triggers on updates could possible cause the code to execute multiple times  in the same execution context causing you to hit the cpu limit.  Consider prventing reentry into triggers or performing check to only run triggers if specific criteria is met.
Otherwise consider refactoring the code if possible to have work executed within the same loop if possible as loops especially nested loops drive up your cpu usage.  Usually workflow on their own dont drive up CPU limit unless triggers are executes due to workflow updates.

Comment: Hi Gareth, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately the workflows I'm dealing with here are both just sending emails out and not causing the trigger to run again. My code itself takes 3148 ms to run, which is well within the 10000 ms CPU run time limit. It's those workflows execution that takes so long for some reason.